# How to fetch multiple documents from Firestore in one React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using `react-firebase-hooks` to interact with my Firebase app. In one page, I need the user data and company data, that live in collections `users` and `companies`. I am using `useAuthState` to first fetch my user, then I had to put my fetching hooks inside of an if statement to check if the user is present.

```
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

let userValue: DocumentData | undefined,
    userLoading: boolean | undefined,
    userError: FirebaseError | undefined,
    userSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> | undefined;

let companyValue: DocumentData | undefined,
    companyLoading: boolean | undefined,
    companyError: FirebaseError | undefined,
    companySnapshot: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> | undefined;

if (user) {
    [userValue, userLoading, userError, userSnapshot] = useDocumentData(
        doc(db, "users", user.uid),
        {
            snapshotListenOptions: {
                includeMetadataChanges: true,
            },
        };
    );

    [companyValue, companyLoading, companyError, companySnapshot] = useDocumentData(
        doc(db, "companies", userValue.companyId));
    );
}
```

If I do it this way, TypeScript complains that `userValue` can be undefined. But, if I place the company call inside of an if statement that checks that it isn't undefined, `if (userValue)`, then I get this error:

> React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by IndexPage.

How can I make it easier to fetch multiple documents from Firebase?